# GUI interaction, waiting until the window is open

Tags: bash

Is there a bash command that waits for a window to open? Right now I'm doing something along the lines of:

```
open-program
sleep 100       # Wait for the program to open
send-keyboard-input
```

Is there a way to have "send-keyboard-input" wait until open-program finishes, eliminating the sleep 100? The time always varies, sometimes it's 90 seconds, sometimes it's 50 second.

Comment: If you know what the window will be called/etc. you can try using something like `wmctrl` to wait until you can see it (by polling/looping). You can do that manually `xprop` too most likely but it may not be as simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
open-program && send-keyboard-input
```